# re.search for dates in a string that are after a specific year

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Say I have a list of movie titles with their year of release:

```
The.Sword.in.the.Stone.1963
The.War.of.The.Worlds.1953
Waynes.World.2.1993
Flora.2017
Candyman.1992
Charming.2018
Candyman.1992
Sollers.Point.2017
Luis.And.The.Aliens.2018
Edie.2017
Daisies.1966
Distant.Voices.Still.Lives.1988
The.Scorpion.King.Book.of.Souls.2018
The.Great.Scout.and.Cathouse.Thursday.1976
Valley.Girl.1983
Psycho.1960
North.By.Northwest.1959
Michael.Jacksons.Moonwalker.1988
```

How do I use regular expressions to delete the movie titles that are released before the year 2000 from the list?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem. questions just asking for code without any attempt are frowned upon here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use regular expressions then you can match any year that does start with `2` using look-ahead and compare it with last 4 characters of your string (assuming last 4 characters of a line is always a year).

```
import re
# assuming file name is file.txt
with open("d:/a.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(r'(?=2)\d{4}',line.rstrip()[-4:]):
            print(line)
# output,

# Flora.2017
# Charming.2018
# Sollers.Point.2017
# Luis.And.The.Aliens.2018
```

using list comprehension,

```
with open("d:/a.txt") as file:
    print([line for line in file if re.match(r'(?=2)\d{4}',line.rstrip()[-4:])])
# output
# ['Flora.2017\n', 'Charming.2018\n', 'Sollers.Point.2017\n', 'Luis.And.The.Aliens.2018\n', 'Edie.2017\n', 'The.Scorpion.King.Book.of.Souls.2018\n']
```

Comment: Thanks. As everyone has stated, the problem is easily solved by searching for 4 digits starting with "20". So I made a re.compile(r'.*?\.20\d\d)

Answer (score 2):

if your year is always the last 4 characters in the file you do not need any regex; you could just do this:

```
from io import StringIO

txt = '''The.Sword.in.the.Stone.1963
The.War.of.The.Worlds.1953
Waynes.World.2.1993
Flora.2017
Candyman.1992
Charming.2018
Candyman.1992
Sollers.Point.2017
Luis.And.The.Aliens.2018
Edie.2017
Daisies.1966
Distant.Voices.Still.Lives.1988
The.Scorpion.King.Book.of.Souls.2018
The.Great.Scout.and.Cathouse.Thursday.1976
Valley.Girl.1983
Psycho.1960
North.By.Northwest.1959
Michael.Jacksons.Moonwalker.1988'''

with StringIO(txt) as file:
    for line in file:
        year = int(line.split('.')[-1])
        # or:
        # year = int(line[-5:])
        if year < 2000:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the first movie was not invented until 1888 and you're looking for movies dating before year 2000, it should be safe to simply look for `1` in the 4th to last character of each title. Assuming that your titles are stored in a list of strings `l`:

```
[t for t in l if t[-4] != '1']
```